# How to make my image move inside and changing figure HTML5 canvas on?

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm am new to HTML5 and need some help. I want the figure to walk to the place I click on in the canvas, I want it to be like an animation it gonna "change" picture to the other walking picture and the figure gonna walk to the cordinates. The image moves but not in a smooth way at all and I want to when I click it changes to the other figure and its going smooth to the position 
I really need help to understand this. This is my code

[figure image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ujrG.png)   |  [figure image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tv0AW.png)

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("client");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
window.addEventListener('mousedown',onDown);

var width = 1200;
var height = 700;

var player = {
    x:50,
    y:100,
    spdx:10,
    spdy:2,
    width:1100,
    height:600,
    img:"images/gubbe1.png",
};

var mouse = {x:0, y:0};

function onDown(event) {
    mouse.x = event.pageX;
    mouse.y = event.pageY;
};

drawEntity = function(something) {
   var imageO = new Image;

   imageO.onload = function() {
       ctx.drawImage(imageO, mouse.x, mouse.y, 64, 150);
   }

   imageO.src = something.img;
}

function clearCanvas() {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
}

function moveimage() {
    clearCanvas();
    ctx.moveTo(mouse.x,mouse.y);
    drawEntity(player);
}

setInterval(moveimage, 100);
```

Comment: You should seriously consider using a gaming engine: https://github.com/collections/javascript-game-engines

Comment: @HelderSepu my longside goal its to make a multiplayer game and then i think i cant use a gaming engine to customize it?

Comment: There are all flavors of gaming engines! The list in the link I sent you those are all Open Source, in the event that the engine does not offer a feature you need you can still change the code of the engine.